# The best way to create job scheduler at runtime based on user input

Tags: java, spring

I want to create n number of job scheduler at runtime based on user input in web page.

Basically I am developing a reporting web application where a user can schedule a report and give email-Id to get the report in email periodically.

I am using Java 1.7, Spring 3.2.8, Spring JdbcTemplate, Birt for developing the application.

Please suggest me the best way or design to achieve the above requirement.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend to have a look at `Quartz` http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `TaskScheduler` and a `Trigger`, as documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-trigger-implementations).

Side note: Spring 3.2.8? 4.1 is about to go GA.